# Unable to connect to DVWA

Tags: mysql, security, web, websecurity, ctf

My Error:
[image]

I've been trying to connect to DVWA but it doesn't seem to be working, my settings are fine I think. [SS for my settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6G0K.png). I'm using MySQL and php5.6. the password for the root user is blank (I've checked it by connecting to DB). Please help!!

[image]

Comment: I recommend you to copy-paste text rather than images, it allows other people to find it later on.

Comment: @sonique I just wanted others to see how my error exactly looks like so i added img instead of text